# How to configure MFTF in Jenkins

Tags: magento2, continuous-integration

In magento2 - Is it possible to configure continuous integration like Jenkins with Magento Functional Test Framework ?

We are using **bitbucket** for our private repositories and Allure for reporting. We are aiming for starting to trigger test suites from a commit in the bit bucket. If the tests are a success, this can trigger another job for deployment.